# How to display elements of a table with specific attribute value in combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, t-sql

I am trying to insert values into a combobox from a table "Employees" from DataSet. I want to display rows with attribute [Role] = 'admin', but I can't find any solution.
My code(It displays names from all rows):

```
cbEmloyees.ItemSource = dataSet.Tables["Employees"].DefaultView;
cbEmployees.DisplayMemberPath = "[Name]";
cbEmployees.SelectedValuePath = "[ID_Employee]";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can apply `RowFilter` to DataView:

```
var dv = dataSet.Tables["Employees"].DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "Role='admin'";
cbEmloyees.ItemSource = dv;
```